# QuantLib Swaption Vol Cube

Tags: programming, implied-volatility, quantlib, swaption

I am currently trying to price swaptions under QuantLib/Python using a **volatility cube** using `ql.SwaptoinVolCube2`. From the documentation:

```
optionTenors = ['1y', '2y', '3y']
swapTenors = [ '5Y', '10Y']
strikeSpreads = [ -0.01, 0.0, 0.01]
volSpreads = [
    [0.5, 0.55, 0.6],
    [0.5, 0.55, 0.6],
    [0.5, 0.55, 0.6],
    [0.5, 0.55, 0.6],
    [0.5, 0.55, 0.6],
    [0.5, 0.55, 0.6],
]

optionTenors = [ql.Period(tenor) for tenor in optionTenors]
swapTenors = [ql.Period(tenor) for tenor in swapTenors]
volSpreads = [[ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(v)) for v in row] for row in volSpreads]

swapIndexBase = ql.EuriborSwapIsdaFixA(ql.Period(1, ql.Years), e6m_yts, ois_yts)
shortSwapIndexBase = ql.EuriborSwapIsdaFixA(ql.Period(1, ql.Years), e6m_yts, ois_yts)
vegaWeightedSmileFit = False

volCube = ql.SwaptionVolatilityStructureHandle(
    ql.SwaptionVolCube2(
        ql.SwaptionVolatilityStructureHandle(swaptionVolMatrix),
        optionTenors,
        swapTenors,
        strikeSpreads,
        volSpreads,
        swapIndexBase,
        shortSwapIndexBase,
        vegaWeightedSmileFit)
)
```

Currently, I am wondering which role the two swap indices play in this?

I assume it has something to do with calculation of ATM and strike-spreads vs ATM, but I do not understand why it requires **two** indices for this.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The swaption vol cube is basically a series of surface layers, each layer refers to a given strike and has vols for combinations of option expiries and swap tenors of the same underlying: a swap with given conventions. That underlying is defined by the `swapIndexBase`.

However, for shorter maturities, the conventions are often different. For example, in Euro, you have swap vs 6M Euribor for tenors > 1Y and swap vs 3M Euribor for the  1Y tenor. The `shortSwapIndexBase` is used to identify this second underlying.

The example on readthedocs could be better in that respect.

Comment: Thanks! And a follow-up: how would I be able to infer the ‚breakpoint‘ between the two conventions? Is that driven by the ‚1Y‘ in the ISDA-Swap? And would I then setup the shorter swap curve with A EUR3M-curve?

Comment: The tenor of the shortSwapIndexBase will define the limit, If swapTenor > shortSwapIndexBase.tenor() use swapIndexBase else use shortSwapIndexBase. Check out the QuantLib source (QuantLib/ql/termstructures/volatility/swaption/swaptionvolcube.cpp)